# How to inherit Q_PROPERTY using Q_GADGET?

Tags: c++, qt

In this **example** i cant inherit `QObject` in the `WinProperty` class because its being inherited by `MainWindow` which already inherits QObjects, then i'm using `Q_GADGET` to be able to inherit its `Q_PROPERTY` at the `MainWindow` class, since Qt 5.5 the [documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.5) states:

> Qt Core
>
> You can now have Q_PROPERTY and Q_INVOKABLE within a Q_GADGET, and there is a way to query the QMetaObject of such gadget using the QMetaType system.

Why when i try to access `test` property from the `MainWindow` class it says "MainWindow has no test property"?

What i'm missing?

```
    class WinProperty
    {
        Q_GADGET
        Q_PROPERTY(int test MEMBER test WRITE setTest)
    public:
        int test = 0;
        void setTest(int xtest)
        {
            qDebug() << "xtest:" << xtest;
            qDebug() << "test:" << test;
        }
    };



    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, public WinProperty
    {
        Q_OBJECT
     public:
    }
```